# Importing R Database Files

Tags: r, read.csv

Trying to figure out why I can't use read.csv to call a data file into R. I have the latest version of R. Do I need to reset my working directory?

carSpeeds <- read.csv(file = 'data/car-speeds.csv')

Comment: Do you get an error message? What do you get when you type `dir("data")` ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do get an error message:
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'data/car-speeds.csv': No such file or directory

When I type dir("data") I get: character(0)

Comment: OK,  that probably means that you DO need to change your working directory. It appears that your current directory does not have a sub-directory called "data".   To see where you are now,  type `getwd()`. use `setwd( xxx )` to set the directory.

Comment: Gotcha. Okay, I reset my working directory that now contains the R file. Thanks